# sort a vector of vectors in c++ by size of each vector

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a vector of vectors and i want to sort it by size of each vector ! 
how could I do that ! 
I want to use sort function but I can't find any parameter in sort function that determines  I want to sort it with size of each content

Comment: See (2) in the description of [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)., then wheel down to the second example, which demonstrates how to use it.

Comment: Each vector have  method  size ()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to specify a predicate:

```
vector<vector<int>> vecs;
vecs.push_back(vector<int>(4));
vecs.push_back(vector<int>(2));
vecs.push_back(vector<int>(1));
vecs.push_back(vector<int>(3));

std::sort(vecs.begin(), vecs.end(), [](const vector<int> & a, const vector<int> & b){ return a.size() < b.size(); });
```

This code sorts the vectors by smallest to largest.